# Second Chance Button for "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account."

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, post-ban

So I was curious if Stack Overflow offers a second chance button. I know a lot of user who get this

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

Is there a way to give good users a second chance?

Comment: Did you read [the given link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824) where you can find how to get a second chance?

Comment: I did read that but I think there should be a physical "Second Chance" Button….

Comment: But why? You get second chance if you follow the given instruction.

Comment: I did that and been waiting for some time to get a second chance :)

Comment: I think there should be a physical button for moderators attention.

Comment: Improve your existing posts, answer some questions helpfully, gain some up votes and _voilà_ - you no longer need a second chance. We're not going out on a limb with trust based on your ability to quickly click a button, which is what got you into the ban in the first place.

Comment: What is your definition of 'good'? The algorithm that stops people from asking questions is in the business of detecting 'bad'.

Comment: Who gets to click the second chance button?

Answer (score 5):

You've already gotten many of your posts closed/deleted/downvoted. I think that's enough chances. **Read the link**, follow the instructions, and your qban will be lifted -- there's your second chance.