# My account was incorrectly merged and then suspended

Tags: support, account-suspension, merge-accounts

So I visited my Stack Overflow account and found this 7-day suspension. Then I checked my Questions Sections and found out question I never asked (It looks like a bug). So does anyone have an idea to fix the bug (And I noticed my Meta Stack Overflow Account Image (and Name) is different from my Stack Overflow Image (and Name))...

Answer (score 8):

The accounts were merged after the following annotation was added by a moderator.

> Same name, same IP, same email, voted exclusively for this account. Appears to be an attempt to circumvent the question ban.

Those two accounts certainly *appear* to be operated by the same person.

Answer (score 1):

Given [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157175/135887), and blindly assuming that you are being truthful here, it looks like your account and someone else's accounts were merged, that the suspension is a direct cause or result, and that there are shenanigans afoot.

You should have received a message telling you *why* the account was suspended.  The [suspension reason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832451/programmer) alleges voting fraud.  It's very likely that something or someone decided that these two accounts belong to the same person (apparently you), and that you were voting on your own posts.

If this is not the case, do you happen to know the person owning the other account?  Perhaps a schoolmate, colleague or roommate?  If so, that's certainly going to look fishy.

For the suspension, this is the right place to ask for help.  A moderator may wander along soon and provide more information.

For the merger, you may wish to [contact Stack Exchange directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) for assistance.  I'm not sure if unmerges are a thing.

Comment: Yes I got this message, how do I fix this Suspension (I didn't deserve it :(

Comment: Question updated with the correct link.

Comment: Do keep in mind that you are going to need to prove that you are not the same person as the person that was suspended.

Comment: I guess I will wait the 7 day for the suspension...